# 404 on WCF service. Starting host and getting correct URI

Tags: asp.net, rest

Im trying to create my first WCF restful service.
I was reading this page: http://www.colossaltechnologies.com/vd/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=128%3Awcf-rest-example&Itemid=101
And tried to copy the code.

However, I dont have my WCF service in a separate application, but added it to my existing web application project. 
The service will not be needed outside the scope of my current project. What I want to achieve is that this rest service can be called from mobile apps (iOS/Android/Windows Phone) that need to be developed.

I noticed  this step in the above tutorial: "Create a Host for the Service"
Now, what I wonder is: do really need to run that code to start the host, and if so: when and how do I run it on a production server?

It seems that I indeed need to do something with that host start, because now when I go to: www.test.com/api/job/bob (I also tried www.test.com/job/bob).
I get a 404.

Below my code, I hope anyone is able to see what Im doing wrong. Am I not using the correct URI? What did I miss?

**Iweddingservice.vb**

```
Imports System.ServiceModel
Imports System.Web
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Namespace RestService
<ServiceContract()>
Public Interface Iweddingservice

    <OperationContract()> _
<Web.WebGet(UriTemplate:="job/{name}")> _
    Function DoJob(name As String) As String

End Interface
End Namespace
```

** weddingservice.svc.vb **

```
Imports System.ServiceModel
Imports System.ServiceModel.Web
Imports System.IO
Imports System.ServiceModel.Activation
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Net

Namespace RestService
Public Class weddingservice
    Implements Iweddingservice

    Public Function DoJob(name As String) As String Implements Iweddingservice.DoJob
        Return String.Format("Hello, {0}", name)
    End Function


End Class

End Namespace
```

** web.config **

```
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="api access 2">
 <match url="^api/job/$" />
 <action type="Rewrite" url="weddingservice.svc/api/job/" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>

<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="RestService.weddingservice">
      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="http://www.test.com/api"/>
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>
      <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" contract="RestService.Iweddingservice" />
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying hosting the service in IIS? If yes, then you cannot provide the address part - it will be implicit by the service file location. For example if your service file `weddingservice.svc` is in the root location then use configuration such as

```
   <system.serviceModel>
     <services>
        <service name="WeddingService">
            <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" contract="RestService.Iweddingservice"
                      behaviorConfiguration="webHttp"/>
        </service>
     </services>
     <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="webHttp">
                <webHttp/>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
     </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Now, you service will be browsable at say - `http://localhost/weddingservice.svc` and your method at `http://localhost/weddingservice.svc/job`. Instead of localhost, you may have whatever host address your web site supports (e.g. www.xyz.com). For eliminating `.svc` extension, you need to use re-write rule or ASp.NET routing.

Finally, if you are not hosting the service in IIS then check your base address - is DNS etc set up correctly for the same. Try the URL w/o any re-writing e.g. `www.test.com/weddingservice.svc/job`.

**EDIT**: It appears that you are still stuck on this. I would suggest that you follow below step-by-step tutorials:

This one should get you started with:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/105273/Create-RESTful-WCF-Service-API-Step-By-Step-Guide

This is a bit detailed and cover quite a few things:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2010/01/07/getting-started-with-wcf-webhttp-services-in-net-4.aspx

Here are other useful links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412172.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd699772.aspx (more samples)

Comment: @Floran, if you see the markup of your svc file then it will have attribute `service="TopTrouwen.weddingservice"`. This class name must match with the class name in your code-behind class. Based on the code that you have posted, the attribute should read `service="RestService.weddingservice"`. And of course, make sure that you build your project without any errors!

Comment: my project builds without errors, even though the markup of the svc file apparently was incorrect like you mentioned! The markup is now: <%@ ServiceHost Language="VB" Debug="true" Service="RestService.weddingservice" CodeBehind="weddingservice.svc.vb" %>
I now get: The type 'RestService.WeddingService', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found.
What can I do?

Comment: @Floran, please check the case - is it `RestService.WeddingService` or `RestService.weddingService`? The error simply indicates that .NET is unable to find type called RestService.WeddingService.

Comment: Yes, I tried changing the casing already. But the casing is exactly as described in my initial post above, and I don't see inconsistent casing there. I do however notice this warning in my web.config: 
"The element 'services' has invalid childelement 'behaviors'. List of possible elements expected:'service,remove,clear'." I dont know if that may cause the error?

Comment: @Floran, `behaviors` is a child of `system.serviceModel` and not of `services` - you probably have incorrect nesting - cross-check the config file.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8303/discussion-between-floran-and-vinayc)

Comment: @Floran, sorry - I don't use chat tools because find them intrusive (while working). Svc end-point is auto-activated in IIS and you don't have start service/host. If you are using VS 2010 then you need run your project (or use view in browser context menu) to get the dev web server started. Yes - it may help you if you post another question with the code that you have and the issue that you are facing. Finally, see my edit - I have given a couple of tutorials that will get you started.

Comment: Ah, I didnt know chat worked that way,first time I used it as well :) But thanks for the links, I will give that a shot first and if it doesnt work out will repost a question with my new status. Thanks for the great help so far!

Comment: Hi, I posted the new question and status here, if you want to have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9557221/the-type-restservice-weddingservice-provided-as-the-service-attribute-value-i
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just keep following the ABC of WCF.
How are you planning to host your service?
If you are planning to host the service using IIS the base address tag will be ignored

Comment: Correct..I will host the service in IIS. I do so now on my local machine and will do so on my production server. So now what? :)